# How to extract a value from JSON column with MariaDB, being this not an exact value in the JSON field?

Tags: sql, json, database, mariadb

I need to extract a field from a JSON string with MariaDB and search for specific patterns in that field.

This field is just a property of all the properties the JSON object has. I had read the documentation and I saw the `JSON_EXTRACT` function. I am still a newbie with databases so I would like some help in this matter.

```
{"user_id":"1","status_id":"1","text":"Hello, world"}
```

Lets say I want to get all the "text" values that have the "world" in the database table. I can extract with `JSON_EXTRACT`. But I want patterns, not absolute values.

How can I do that?

Comment: When you say "I want patterns", you mean you want to be able to filter by a pattern? E.g. `Hello*` in `text` so you get `Hello, world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the value with `json_extract()`, and then do pattern matching with `like`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where json_extract(my_json_col, '$.text') like '%world%'
```